# Cycle loop in bash script

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, cycle

I made this quick and dirty bash script for this desired result:

1a
2b
3c
4a
5b
6c
......

I made a lot of testing but didn't find a proper way to write it if I can have your suggestions.

Here is the working code I found :

```
for ((i=1; i<11; i++))
do 
    echo $((i++))a
    echo $((i++))b
    echo $((i++))c
done
```

Comment: It is not clear from the question or the code what's wrong with this. There is also no nested loop here, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modular arithmetic to cycle through the list of letters.

```
letters=(a b c)
for ((i=1; i<11; i++)); do
    echo "$i${letters[(i-1)%3]}"
done
```

The expression `(i-1)%3` will cycle over 0, 1, 2 as `i` increases.